# Django Url Dispatcher issue when using a prefix

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Working :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', views.index),
    (r'^test/$|test/(\d+)/$', views.test_page),
    (r'^(name)/$', views.index),
    (r'^(username)/$', views.index),
)
```

Not working :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    (r'^$', index),
    (r'^test/$|test/(\d+)/$', test_page),
    (r'^(name)/$', index),
    (r'^(username)/$', index),
)
```

Error :

```
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    name 'index' is not defined
Exception Location: /home/nolhian/Documents/Test/../test/urls.py in <module>, line 8
```

I followed the docs to do this, where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the prefix, you must specify your views as strings:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^test/$|test/(\d+)/$', 'test_page'),
    (r'^(name)/$', 'index'),
    (r'^(username)/$', 'index'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I missed that !